# Wrapping multiple method calls into one if statement

Tags: c#, validation, if-statement

I have a validation method that I call to validate the fields on my form. I want to put these in an if statement check to see if they return true then in my else statement insert them into my database. i already have the method declared and the insert method declared. How can I write this if statement to check to see if all the validation methods return true?

My method validation calls:

```
formValidation(firstnameTextBox.Text);
formValidation(lastnameTextBox.Text);
formValidation(usernameTextBox.Text);
formValidation(passwordTextBox.Text);
formValidation(emailTextBox.Text);
formValidation(cellnumberTextBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the AND operator (`&&`)

```
if(formValidation(firstnameTextBox.Text) &&
formValidation(lastnameTextBox.Text) &&
formValidation(usernameTextBox.Text) &&
formValidation(passwordTextBox.Text) &&
formValidation(emailTextBox.Text) &&
formValidation(cellnumberTextBox.Text))
{
}
```

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094966/wrapping-multiple-method-calls-into-one-if-statement/21095002#comment31732257_21095002), if you want all of the methods to be run (to display the relevant errors for each field) no matter what, and to not stop as soon as it hits the first error, you can use a non-short circuiting AND, which is the `&` operator.

Alternatively, you could put the textboxes into a collection and act on that collection:

```
var fieldsToValidate = new TextBox[]{firstnameTextBox, lastnameTextBox, ...}
if(fieldsToValidate.All(field => formValidation(field.Text));
```

Comment: Servy I didn't know it would be that simple though.

Comment: Not exactly the question, but IF you want to make sure all of these would run, just use a single ampersand. As written the "formValidation" function is only called until the first false is returned (Lazy evaluation)

Comment: @drew_w what do you mean?

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos Just try both and see for yourself; it should be clear at that point.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos If you write "if (x() && y()) {...}" then when x returns true, y will be called. If x returns false, y will never be called. If you use a single ampersand, both x and y will be called every time, no matter what the other returns.